# Parse XML Feed With PHP To Find If Specific Data Exists

Tags: php, xml, rss, simplexml

I need to check if Team1 exists in the XML feed.  If Team1 appears twice in the XML feed, I need to output only the first instance.  So far I can only output both instances. How do I accomplish this?

```
$str = <<<'XML'
<DATAS>
    <DATA>
        <VISITOR>Team6</VISITOR>
        <HOME>Team7</HOME>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
        <VISITOR>Team1</VISITOR>
        <HOME>Team2</HOME>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
        <VISITOR>Team3</VISITOR>
        <HOME>Team1</HOME>
    </DATA>
    <DATA>
        <VISITOR>Team4</VISITOR>
        <HOME>Team5</HOME>
    </DATA>
</DATAS>    
XML;


$data = new SimpleXMLElement($str);

$found = false;

foreach ($data->DATA as $item) {
    $teamh = $item->HOME;
    $teamv = $item->VISITOR;


    if ($teamh == 'Team1' || $teamv == 'Team1') { 
        $found = true;

    echo 'Home Team: ' . $data->DATA->HOME . "\n";
    echo 'Away Team: ' . $data->DATA->VISITOR . "\n";
   }

}
```

Comment: Can team 1 appear once in home and once in visitor, or just once over all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPath. Selecting nodes on a DOM tree is easy with it. (SimpleXML uses a DOM in the background). Here are to methods for it `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` and `DOMXpath::evaluate()`.

Select all event data:
`/DATAS/DATA`

Only if VISITOR or HOME is "Team1":
`/DATAS/DATA[VISITOR='Team1' or HOME='Team1']`

Count them:
`count(/DATAS/DATA[VISITOR='Team1' or HOME='Team1'])`

Limit to the first found node:
`/DATAS/DATA[VISITOR='Team1' or HOME='Team1'][1]`

`SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` always returns an array of SimpleXMLElement objects. So it can not directly execute the `count(...)` Xpath expression.

You can of course use the PHP function `count()` on the return value.

```
count($datas->xpath("/DATAS/DATA[VISITOR='Team1' or HOME='Team1']"));
```

If you only want to output the first event data for a team if it exists you will not need the count. Limiting the result in XPath will return a list/array with a single element or an empty list.

### SimpleXML Example

```
$datas = simplexml_load_string($str);

$eventCount = count($datas->xpath("/DATAS/DATA[VISITOR='Team1' or HOME='Team1']"));
echo "Team1 is included $eventCount time(s) in the feed.\n";

$events = $datas->xpath("/DATAS/DATA[VISITOR='Team1' or HOME='Team1'][1]");
foreach ($events as $event) {
  echo "Visitor: {$event->VISITOR}, Home: {$event->HOME}\n"; 
}
```

### DOM Example

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($str);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$eventCount = $xpath->evaluate("count(/DATAS/DATA[VISITOR='Team1' or HOME='Team1'])");
echo "Team1 is included $eventCount time(s) in the feed.\n";

$events = $xpath->evaluate("/DATAS/DATA[VISITOR='Team1' or HOME='Team1'][1]");
foreach ($events as $event) {
  $visitor = $xpath->evaluate('string(VISITOR)', $event);
  $home = $xpath->evaluate('string(HOME)', $event);
  echo "Visitor: $visitor, Home: $home\n"; 
}
```

Comment: SimpleXML basically what I answered. nice addition is [1], wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Sorry, I thought about just commenting, but I wanted to add some more explanation about the XPath expression and the DOM alternative.

Comment: Thank you for the help, this worked great!  Both solutions work for  me, I chose this one because I can't accept both questions as correct.  Thank you for the insight to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to accomplish **task 1**, check if and how often Team1 is in the feed:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$team1 = $xml->xpath("/DATAS/DATA[VISITOR='Team1' or HOME='Team1']");
echo "Team1 is included " . count($team1) . " time(s) in the feed.";
```

This examples uses `xpath()` to select all `<DATA>` nodes having Team1 as either `<VISITOR>` or `<HOME>`.
The result is an array of `SimpleXML` Elements that can be counted.

see it working: https://eval.in/230136

For **task 2**, having only Team1 output once (in contrast to every Team only once), this is a looping way:

```
$team1count = 0;

foreach ($xml->DATA as $event) {

    $t[0] = $event->VISITOR;
    $t[1] = $event->HOME;

    $hasteam1 = in_array('Team1', $t);

    if (($hasteam1 AND $team1count == 0) OR (!$hasteam1)) { 

        echo "Visitor: " . $t[0] . PHP_EOL;
        echo "Home: " . $t[1] . PHP_EOL;
    }

    $team1count = $team1count + $hasteam1;
}
```

This approach is using a check if Team1 is `<VISITOR>` or `<HOME>` in the current node, and counting the occurrences of Team1. Teams are echoed if either Team1 is there, but the counter = 0, or if Team1 is not there. Of course, the counter has to be incremented if Team1 was there.

see it working: https://eval.in/230152

**But wait, there's another solution, let's build on what we did for task 1**:

```
// same code as above:
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$team1 = $xml->xpath("/DATAS/DATA[VISITOR='Team1' or HOME='Team1']");
```

Now, we simply delete all `<DATA>` nodes with Team1 but the 1st from the XML:

```
$c = 0;
foreach ($team1 as $event) {
    if ($c > 0) unset($event[0]);
    $c++;
}
```

`$team1` is an array containing all nodes with team1, so we iterate over it. We don't delete the 1st one, but all the other ones by counting with `$c` and do `unset()` only for `$count > 0`.

`unset($event[0])` deletes a `<DATA>` node from the XML tree.

Now, we simply have to run over the XML and output all the remaining nodes:

```
foreach ($xml->DATA as $event) 
    echo "Visitor: " . $event->VISITOR . ", Home: " . $event->HOME . PHP_EOL;
```

See all of this in action: https://eval.in/230157

Comment: Thank you for the insight to this problem.  Great solutions to my problem!